# Azure Lookup Activity Query Option to Parameterized Select Statement

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to do the select query option in my lookup activity to connect azure sql database but if I am passing multiple parameter with condition. I am getting failed activity. kindly help me.

ForEach loop @item will give the dynamic table values to pass our lookup activity.

```
select * from tablename where columnname ='@{item().table} IS NOT NULL' AND columnname='@{item().table}!="" '
```

I want to apply the column should not give the NULL value and EMPTY value. so that I am using

> NOT NULL

keyword and checking `column!=''` also

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get better answers, you should provide more detail. You say you get a failed activity but don't provide the specific failure or the error message.

Also, you should be able to look at the run/debug detail and see the constructed query, which should give some clues as to the issue.

Without that information, I'm just guessing, but the following query does not make sense to me because the ' marks encapsulate IS NOT NULL and != "":

```
select * from tablename where columnname ='@{item().table} IS NOT NULL' AND columnname='@{item().table}!="" '
```

I assume you mean something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE columnname {@item().table} IS NOT NULL
AND columnname {@item().table} != ""
```

Do you see the difference between these two? I'm also assuming here that "tablename" and "columnname" are placeholders for known values, not that they are also dynamic.